# Responsive Button sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I've just started using Semantic UI and I've hit a bit of a wall. I have 2 buttons in a div. These buttons should be large on desktop and small on mobile. I've followed the Semantic conventions and added the classes 'large desktop small mobile', but the buttons do not resize on mobile.

Is this just not a feature of Semantic UI, or am I missing something? The official documentation for Buttons doesn't seem to make mention of it, nor does the page on Responsive Elements.

https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your button?

Comment: I'm using semantic-ui-react. There's nothing to show - should the classes I added be working?

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a [mcve].

Comment: The idea behind the question was for someone to tell me the classes I should use to achieve my desired result, or to tell me that Semantic UI doesn't support this. Judging from your comment, are you saying that it should be working? I can't exactly send you the whole React app, and the only pertinent part of this is the classes I apply to the Button component, or the `size` attribute.

The same question could be asked of any element/ Component with a size attribute, such as Steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this (https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/756) Semantic UI doesn't have classes that work like that (you might be thinking of [bootstrap classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries)). The suggested work-around in that post is to utilize the @media for your classes.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for letting me know.